# Wamp windows 8 problems

Tags: php, mysql, apache-http-server, wamp

I am unable to see the menus that normally appear when I hover/select apache,php or mysql. These windows refuse to float to the lefthand side of the wamp server root menu, I barely see the edge of the submenu as it floats off to the right side of the screen.

I have tried playing with the screen resolution with no luck.

The other problems I am haviong is that it will not run in "offline" mode and I cant get curl to work.

I have been through the other posts about the last 2 problems but my main issue right now is simply being able to see the submenues for the settings...

Comment: Maybe you should look for answers at http://serverfault.com/.

Comment: What colour is the wampmanager icon in the system tray?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that you have installed these Visual C++ runtimes, both are required

```
[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)][1]

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x64)][2]
```